# Firemonkey Cut of controls using D XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I want to redesign an GUI made with the Fire Monkey Framework using DELPHI XE 2.
I placed a second panel on my GUI designer and want to move components / controls inside this panel.

I failed to use  function  to cut the components and I can not place them inside the panel with .
Is ths way of moving componetens different between VCL and FM ?  I did this job many times in my VCL applications

Comment: Is there a DFM file that you can edit directly? That is how I normally make these kind of changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the XE2 IDE which intermittently disables cut/copy/paste from Edit menu.

If you switch between Welcome Page tab and back to the form's tab in IDE, it should temporarily fix the issue and restore cut/copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marcus` answer, with FMX (at least the version included in XE5) the easiest way is to just use the Structure View window; it's easiest just to left-click and drag the control from one parent to another, and the form is updated to show the new layout automatically:

Dropping two panels, arranging side by side, and dropping a label on the left panel:

[image: Label on Panel1]

Dragging the label (via the Structure View) from Panel1 to Panel2:

[image: Label moved to Panel2]